# Delphi - Draw a rectangle with the mouse

Tags: delphi

I'm creating a window the user could use to draw shapes on a TScrollBox with the mouse. First i'm trying to give the possibility of drawing a simple rectangle and make it disappear when mouse is up.

Below is a minimalist version of my code :

```
procedure TXXX.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin 
  if (Button = mbLeft) and MyCondition then begin
    FStartPlace.X := X;
    FStartPlace.Y := Y;
    FEndPlace.X := X;
    FEndPlace.Y := Y;
    FCapturing := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TXXX.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin   
  if MyCondition and FCapturing then begin
    Canvas.Rectangle(FStartPlace.X, FStartPlace.Y, FEndPlace.X, FEndPlace.Y);
    FEndPlace.X := X;
    FEndPlace.Y := Y;
    Canvas.Rectangle(FStartPlace.X, FStartPlace.Y, FEndPlace.X, FEndPlace.Y);
  end;
end;    

procedure TXXX.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if MyCondition then begin
    FCapturing := False;
    //Canvas.Rectangle(FStartPlace.X, FStartPlace.Y, FEndPlace.X, FEndPlace.Y); // Draw a rectangle on the previous one to make it disapear ?
  end;
end;
```

The problems are, when i draw back on my previous rectangle, i can't "erase/delete" it. The second problem is how to make it disapear in the MouseUp procedure ?

[image]

I'm pretty sure I have to use "Xor" but I don't understand how it works. I tried to implement `Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmXor;`but without succeed. Do you have any advice ?

Thank you

[UPDATE]
In the Paint procedure, I draw a "dot grid" in memory in order that it doesn't induce flickering.

```
procedure TXXX.Paint();
var
  X, Y: Integer;
  Buffer: TBitmap;
begin
  Buffer := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Buffer.Width := Width;
    Buffer.Height := Height;   
    X := 0;
    Y := Height;
    while X <= Buffer.Width do begin
      while Y >= 0 do begin
        Buffer.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y]:= clBlack;
        Y := Y - FStep;
      end;
      X := X + FStep;
      Y := Height;
    end;

    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Buffer);
  finally
    Buffer.free
  end;

  if FCapturing then
    Canvas.Rectangle(FStartPlace.X, FStartPlace.Y, FEndPlace.X, FEndPlace.Y);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't draw on the `Canvas` from outside on the `Paint()` method. You are already saving your drawing coordinates, just replace the `Canvas` calls with `Invalidate()` instead, and then do only the latest drawing when the `Paint()` method is called.

```pascal
procedure TXXX.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin 
  if (Button = mbLeft) and MyCondition then begin
    FStartPlace.X := X;
    FStartPlace.Y := Y;
    FEndPlace.X := X;
    FEndPlace.Y := Y;
    FCapturing := True;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TXXX.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin   
  if FCapturing then begin
    FEndPlace.X := X;
    FEndPlace.Y := Y;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;    

procedure TXXX.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if FCapturing then begin
    FCapturing := False;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TXXX.Paint;
begin
  if FCapturing then
    Canvas.Rectangle(FStartPlace.X, FStartPlace.Y, FEndPlace.X, FEndPlace.Y);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer ! That's almost perfect. There is just flickering cause my "dot grid" is painting everytime. Is it possible maybe, to paint only a region of the control ?

Comment: There is no "dot grid" being drawn in the code shown. Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. I have updated my post with the paint method showing how I construct the "dot grid" (illustrated on the screenshot).

Comment: What is stopping you from simply drawing the rectangle on to the `TBitmap` on top of the grid? On the other hand, why are you re-creating the `TBitmap` on every paint, rather than caching and reusing it? It's content is not changing unless the component's size changes (or you add the rectangle on top of it).